# SQL Server database schema and compliance audit tools

Tags: sql-server, validation, t-sql

Colleagues,

Are there any tools available for validating a SQL Server (2016/17) database schema against a set of design rules, naming conventions, best practices (including security) etc.

I want to be able to say "What in this database doesn't meet this set of rules" or compliance requirements.

Some examples of the type of rules I'm talking about would be like:
- Primary key fields should be the first in the table.
- Foreign keys should have an index on that field.
- Field names ending 'xxx' should be of a certain type.
- Fields with a constraint limiting it it certain values it should have a default.
- The database is not security compliant for sunch and such reasons et. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of places from where you can start. Firs of all, let's start with the [Brent Ozar's blitz routines](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/):

- sp_Blitz
- sp_BlitzCache
- sp_BlitzFirst
- sp_BlitzIndex

You can download the pack, there is documentation, GitHub repository and some demonstration videos. Execute them and explore the results.

The above is more about performance and if you download (and you should always use the latest version) the [SSMS 17.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) you can run a `Vulnerability Assessment`. More details [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-vulnerability-assessment), but basically you can check:

- Meet compliance requirements that require database scan reports.
- Meet data privacy standards.
- Monitor a dynamic database environment where changes are difficult to
  track.

It is new report and new things are coming as availability to schedule the report and new checks. You ask for features in the comments sections in the article.

---

In the past I have used a little bit [SQL COP tests](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLServerCentral/121037/). You can check them, but I believe the Brent Ozar's pack is up-to-date, better and the choice here (but you can check if you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Policy-Based Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/monitor-and-enforce-best-practices-by-using-policy-based-management). Set your own best practices/enforce policies and evaluate your SQL Server config and databases to a standard you need. You can evaluate multiple servers via Central Management Server. Policy-Based Management is built-in to SQL Server.

**Updated the answer from comment:**
if you are looking for a 3rd-party tools, you can check [Apex](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/pci-compliance-for-sql-server-dbas/) or [Quest](https://www.quest.com/products/change-auditor-for-sql-server/). They've built software for Auditing SQL Server. Or you could build custom audit scripts based on your requirements. Security compliance  like PCI/HPIAA or SOX also requires you to audit the OS so better to build your own script. Usually external Auditors will give you a set of questions or standards that requires to be harden.

Personally I would first try the built-in tools (PBM) provided by Microsoft and if the requirement doesn't met the standards you need, try to look for 3rd party tools or roll your own.

Comment: dco, Thanks for an answer, but this approach is not good enough. I need to verify databases I have against design best practices, security standards and HIPAA/PCI compliance (if possible).
There were tools like SQLCop and SSW SQL Auditor before, but they all outdated and no longer supported.